# Linq select statement but require no from line

Tags: sql, linq

So in Sql you can do a simple line not pulling from any database, For example
`Select 'hello world'`

what's the Linq equivalent to that? and instead of 'hello world' I'd like to use the variable
hello which contains 'hello world'

```
        var helloworld = new {SayWhat = "Hello", ToWhom = "world", Name = "Bob", Surname = "Morris"};
        var hello = new {SayWhat = "Bye", ToWhom = "world", Name = "Michael", Surname = "Smith"};
        var Combine = helloworld.Union(hello);
```

Comment: `var hello = "hello world";` trust me, no database calls

Comment: Is it linq? Don't think so, trust me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL a `SELECT` without `FROM` is used to create a single row of data. One way to achieve the same effect in LINQ is to use [`Enumerable.Repeat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348899%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), like this:

```
var hello = "Hello, world!";
IEnumerable<string> noFromLinq = Enumerable.Repeat(hello, 1);
```

You can do the same without LINQ by creating a single-element array:

```
IEnumerable<string> noFromArray = new[] { hello };
```

> How do i add Extra columns into that?

Like this:

```
var helloMultipleColumns = new { SayWhat = "Hello", ToWhom = "world"};
var noFromMulticolumnLinq = Enumerable.Repeat(helloMultipleColumns, 1);
var noFromMulticolumnArray = new[] { helloMultipleColumns };
```

Comment: How do i Add Extra columns into that? Sorry I haven't seen that kind of syntax before.

Comment: Is it possible to Union that Row with another?

Comment: @user2785177 Yes, as long as the other row has exactly the same list of fields, including capitalization of their names and their types.